# How can i find the roots of this equation?

Tags: calculus

$$(x^2-4x+1)\exp x =1$$

I need to find the roots of this equation. $x$ is a real number.

How can I find out how many roots this equation has?

Comment: **Hint:** The real root is obvious ($ x = 0$), but the other two - numerical methods - like Newton's Method. Plot each side to see these intersections. Are you familiar with the intermediate value theorem and mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes I know Newton´s method, but should i use the first derivate to find roots?

Comment: The generalized Lambert function described here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303839763_Fleshing_out_the_Generalized_Lambert_W_Function and in other papers, gives a method for finding the number of roots, and the roots of functions of the form $e^{-x}=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)...(x-x_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $f(x)=(x^2-4x+1)\exp(x) - 1$ is $f'(x)=(x+1)(x-3)\exp(x)$ which is positive for $x < -1$ and $x \gt 3$ and negative for $-1 < x \lt 3$, so $f(x)$ has at most three zeros

Meanwhile

- $f(x) \to -1$ as $x \to -\infty$
- $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$
- $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=-3 < 0$

so $f(x)$ has exactly three zeros, one at $x=0$, one with $x < -1$ (in fact about $-3.164$) and one with $x > 3$ (in fact about $3.739$)

Answer (score 0):

To see how many roots the equation, you can graph 
$$
e^{-x}
$$
and 
$$
x^2-4x+1
$$
pretty easily. The points of intersection correspond to your roots.